# Oracle Sql matching date column to sysdate error

Tags: sql, oracle, select, sysdate

I am trying to match columns from different tables, matching them to today's date using `SYSDATE`. The ouput is actually populating the date column with today's date on all rows instead of just one row that actually has today's date in it.

```
SELECT building.building_code, 
    building.building_name, 
    room_booking.booking_date
FROM building,
     room_booking,
     dual
WHERE to_date(booking_date) = trunc(sysdate)
```

OUTPUT IS:

```
BUILDING_CODE BUILDING_NAME   BOOKING_DATE
------------- --------------- ------------
A             ARCADIA         <17-mar-13>  
B             BELIZE          <17-mar-13>  
C             CAMDEN          <17-mar-13>  
D             DENVER          <17-mar-13>  
E             EXETER          <17-mar-13>  
F             FORT PORTAL     <17-mar-13>  
G             GRAMPIAN        <17-mar-13>  
H             HELVITICA       <17-mar-13>  
I             INVICTA         <17-mar-13>  
J             JULIET          <17-mar-13>  

10 rows selected
```

There should be only one row in the result as there is only 1 row with today's date in it. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: You need a join condition on your two tables (and you don't need `dual`).

Comment: Thanks Mat - dual removed now

Comment: Why do you have `TO_DATE` around `booking_date`? Is it a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're not joining the tables `room_booking` and `building`, producing a cartesian product on it.

```
SELECT 
    b.building_code, 
    b.building_name, 
    r.booking_date
FROM building b
        JOIN room_booking   r /* missing join condition here: ON r.building_code = b.building_code */
WHERE 
    TO_DATE(r.booking_date) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
```

Comment: Watch out for implicit date format conversion errors.  This code will not work if a session executes `alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';`.  You probably want to use `TRUNC(r.booking_date)` instead of `TO_DATE(r.booking_date)`.